# A futuristic word puzzle

Tags: riddle, word

After being inspired by all the other word puzzles on here I am unable to solve, I decided to try to write my own. It might be too easy, but I hope you enjoy!

> My prefix is short for myself
> My suffix is metric
> My infix can be made from a tree
> My whole is something you can see

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Hologram? Holo can be short for hologram. Gram and Log have been explained by Rand al'Thor. It can be seen. It is futuristic as it is seen in sci movies such as star wars

Comment: @musefan your comment contains a spoiler

Comment: Was it really too much effort to just explain the solution in your own answer...

Comment: @UglyBlueCat: I am not an advocate of that stupid rot13 to avoid spoilers (just don't look at comments on answers if you don't want spoilers), but I think in this instance they did stand out a bit too much, so I have removed.

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 8):

I think you are

> KILOGRAM.

*My prefix is short for myself*

> KILO.

*My suffix is metric*

> GRAM.

*My infix can be made from a tree*

> LOG.

*My whole is something you can see*

> I guess you can see it on a scale?

Not sure about the significance of "futuristic" in the title.

Comment: That's a great guess, and actually does work with the clues, but is not the word i was thinking of.

Comment: Also good, this one is.